# Can anyone explain the Zaeed cutscene in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I did not make Zaeed loyal in ME2. I played through the Volus Ambassador mission, but have no idea what happened. One minute I am talking to the Volus ambassador on some kind of Plantronics earpiece, then I hear weird shooting noises, then you walk in and Zaeed is bleeding all over the place.

What happened? Did the Volus shoot him? How? Why? What?

Comment: Not make zaeed loyal? How can you not? It's easy to get the adiquate paragon/renegade required. And at that how did he survive the suicide mission unloyal?

Comment: Probably did not have the required paragon when I did his mission, because he was not happy with Shepard at the end of that mission. You do not need 100% loyalty to have everyone survive the suicide mission, it is more a matter of how you choose to use your team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shepard's presence on the Volus ambassador's commline convinced Zaeed that it was better to protect him - at least until Shepard can get a chance to speak with the Volus.

Unfortunately, Zaeed's partners want to stick to their original plan of killing the ambassador. Zaeed refuses to let them kill the ambassador, and they wind up getting in a gunfight over the volus, and ultimately wind up killing each other. If your Zaeed is loyal, he'll survive this extrication (as always), otherwise, he gives his life saving the ambassador.

Comment: Ah. OK. The placement of the bodies did not make that very clear, and I guess I missed that part of the conversation somehow. Thanks!